# Custom post type items open in archives?

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

I have my own custom post type under:

wordpress/custom

But when I open any item of this post type they open in:

wordpress/archives/custom/title

Why there's 'archives' and how to get rid of this from my urls?

The taxonomy is registered like below:

```
register_taxonomy("our_frontpage_types", array("frontpage"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categories", "singular_label" => "Category", "rewrite" => true));
```

And the post is registered like:

```
add_action('init', 'fp_register');
```

- UPDATE *

Ok, now I know it was a problem with permalinks, BUT /%category%/%postname% is far from perfection. Is there something like %section%/%postname%?

Comment: Try setting `'with_front' => false` inside the rewrite array for your post type, eg. `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'your-slug', 'with_front' => false )` ... the same can be done with taxonomies to.

Comment: @t31os changes nothing :(

Comment: What's your site url and home url set to? Is archive included in either, if not, that's part of your permlink structure and setting `with_front` to false will remove that part of the URL(so it must be one of those two things - permalink structure or home/site url).

Comment: @t31os as far I understand I should search for these in admin wp-admin / settings / general. The Wordpress and site address is the same - http://localhost/wordpress . And the permalink structure is /archives/%post_id% - well... Hmmm... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress will add archives base in the url if it thinks that the page an archive and when i had the problem it was because i named the custom post type and my custom taxonomy the same, is that the case?

Comment: I've added taxonomy to the first post.

Comment: add your register post type code

Comment: also what do you see as url in the edit post type page near the slug field?

Comment: @בניית אתרים i see 'http://localhost/wordpress/archives/frontpage/lifelong-support' there.

Comment: whats your  permalink structure? and home/site url?